# Bundle pricing for all products on Wordpress using Woo-commerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

How do I create specific bundle prices for all my products as well as being able to sell them individually. So if you look at the site I'm building - http://knittingcompany.co.uk. You will see items for £1.99 and £6.50.

I want to sell all of these individually, but also to give an option to buy them as a bundle. I want customers to have the option to buy 10 of £1.99 items for £10, and buy 3 of the £6.50 items for £15.

I've installed Woo Commerce Product Bundles, but I can't seem to have the facility to be able to allow all the products to be sold in bundles. Customers should be able to select any of the items within the same price bracket and have the offer available.

Unless I'm using the plugin wrong I think I may have bought the wrong plugin to do what I want it to do.

Does anyone know how to help either using this plugin or by any other means?

Thanks

Comment: [How to bundle products with WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/group-bundle-products-woocommerce/)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thank you I think it's the product bundle section just need to read through the documents to get it to do what I need it to do. Hopefully the plugin wasn't a waste of money then!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that might be interested in this the product bundle plugin from woocommerce wasn't the plugin I needed to carry out the function I wanted. It's another plugin called dynamic pricing from woocommerce. In case anyone else is interested